# how to solve the ValueError: is not in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am having the same problem here while it is on the list actually. probably there is another mistake here is my code check it, please:

```
base = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
c= base.index(a)
```

the a is  input and I made sure it was "o", "k"

```
ValueError: ['o', 'k'] is not in list
```

Also, I can't put the `try:` because this line has to be done or the whole program doesn't work

Comment: This is the expected behavior. `list.index` raises a `ValueError` when the arguement is not contained in the list. Do you expect the list `['o', 'k']` to be contained in `base`?

Comment: Show how you're setting `a` from the input.

Comment: I am a beginner but I think yes, as you see the ['o', 'k'] exist in the base list. I can't see why it didn't work !!

Comment: @Barmar it's a bit complicated.

Comment: `current_position1 = split(current_position)` and `task, current_position = input("presise if you want to code or to decode? than put you message: ").split()` never mind the task part it's for another line

Comment: `split()` returns a list. `base` is a list of strings, you can only get the index of one of those strings. It won't automatically recurse into the list.

Comment: Ok, I see and how can I fix that ??

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]. There are too many unknowns in your current code.

Comment: Thank you, it was pretty helpful. You seem to be a professional did you learn it online or in normal class ?? Because I have been searching for a good platform to keep learning but I can't find good ones do you happen to know a good one ???

Comment: @khaled Youtuber "sentdex" has a very helpful python tutorial playlist at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for each letter in the given input like this,
Input:

```
ip = ["o", "k"]
c = (base.index(i) for i in ip)
```

Output:

```
for i in c:
...     print(i)
...
14
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Base does not appear to be a list of lists.

Instead of :

```
if ['o','k'] in list:
```

You should use:

```
if 'o' in list and 'k' in list:
```